# Which query operations take advantage of indexes?

Tags: database, indexing, database-performance

I am wondering which kind of operations use indexes for their advantage.

Obviously "like" (without pattern matching) and "=" will work pretty good.
I guess that >, <, >=, <= will use the advantages of indexes as well.

**But are there other operations that take advantage of indexes?**

Answer (score 0):

Integrate if I miss:

**Join** can use indexes.

Also **sort operations** can use indexes, see for example: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181154%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Unique constraint is verified using index.

Foreign key will **lookup** on indexex.

Comment: Can you provide some documentation on that last point? SQL Server in most default installations is case-insensitive, which would not work for a bitwise comparison. And that doesn't really address the question of whether an index can be used or not.

Comment: @alroc sorry, made edit to my answer, last line was wrong. I had in mind Postgresql (question is not specific) but it can use indexes on bi just on exact search.

Answer (score 0):

> **Most operations that involve reading any data will benefit from**
>   **indexes.**

Data is stored on disk. If you try to fetch data without using an index, it will do a linear search with average case complexity of O(n/2) - which means to say that, considering an average case, it will take half a million comparison to find a data point from a data set that contains a million records. However, if you do it using an index, you will bring it down to O(log(n)). Here's a chart from http://bigocheatsheet.com/ explaining all this:

[image]

Imagine any operation you do - it all comes down to sorting and searching. Doesn't matter whether it is a SELECT, an UPDATE or a DELETE.

Although, indexes do speed up the system but that happens only when indexes are used wisely. In a write-only master database, you might not want many indexes because every time you insert a record, there'll be an overhead of recomputing the index. You might want to put indexes on slave but that too after careful consideration because an ALTER will be very costly if there are many indexes. You also have to keep in mind that indexes do take up space, especially indexes on text columns.

As for the question about **LIKE**:

**LIKE** will also utilize indexes, even in pattern matching but only when you do:

```
LIKE "something%"
```

It won't work when you write

```
LIKE "%something%"
```

Pattern searching in relational databases is not a very scalable idea. Depending upon the use case, you might want to opt ElasticSearch to take you home. However, there are RDBMSs which provide full-text functionality.